# Excel - copy one sheet to all opened workbooks

Tags: excel

I am trying to copy one sheet from one workbook to all opened workbooks.

Workbooks that I want to copy that sheet to are located in many different folders, but I plan to locate them all and open them all.

Using Excel 2010, I can do that manually for each opened workbook, right click on sheet - move or copy - select ONE of the opened books... what I am tying to accomplish is equivalent to selecting ALL opened workbooks. Copied sheets could be placed at end of existing sheets.

Sheet that I want to copy to other workbooks contains links to other sheet in same workbook, but other workbooks that this sheet will be copied to already have a sheet with same name, so that is probably not a problem?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution:
This macro copies the active sheet to all the open workbooks except the one it's in:

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim sh As Worksheet

```
Set sh = ActiveSheet

For Each wb In Application.Workbooks
    If Not sh.Parent Is wb Then
        sh.Copy After:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count)
    End If
Next wb
```